# Load data from cloudkit into tableView cells but only within the last 72 hours (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cloud

I have all the code and records set up exactly the way I want too!  You can create a post and it saves the post in a record on cloudKit.  The problem is I would only like to load the data/post made within the last 72 hours.

How can I implement that within my code? Here is all my code for the tableView:

```
    class SweetsTableViewController: UITableViewController {




var sweets = [CKRecord]()
var refresh:UIRefreshControl!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    refresh = UIRefreshControl()
    refresh.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to Refresh Page")
    refresh.addTarget(self, action: "loadData", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(refresh)

    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 1000.0





    loadData()

}

func loadData () {
    sweets = [CKRecord]()

    let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Sweet", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
    query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
    publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results:[CKRecord]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if let sweets = results {
            self.sweets = sweets
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
                self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 1000.0
                self.refresh.endRefreshing()
            })
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func sendSweet(sender: AnyObject) {



    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Post", message: "Enter your Post", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField:UITextField) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Your Post"

    }

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Send", style: .Default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        let textField = alert.textFields!.first!
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        let label = defaults.objectForKey("label") as? String

        if textField.text != "" {
            let newSweet = CKRecord(recordType: "Sweet")
            newSweet["content"] = textField.text
            newSweet["label"] = label

            let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
            publicData.saveRecord(newSweet, completionHandler: { (record:CKRecord?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                    self.sweets.insert(newSweet, atIndex: 0)
                    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
                    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Top)
                    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
                    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 1000.0
                    self.tableView.endUpdates()

                   })

                }else{
                    print(error)
                }
            })
        }
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}



override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return sweets.count
}
func configureTableView() {
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 1000.0
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 1000.0
    cell.textLabel?.sizeToFit()
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0



    if sweets.count == 0 {
        return cell
    }


        let sweet = sweets[indexPath.row]


    if let sweetContent = sweet["content"] as? String {

        let label = sweet["label"] as? String

        let dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormat.dateFormat = "- h:mm a"
        let dateString = dateFormat.stringFromDate(sweet.creationDate!)

        cell.textLabel?.text = sweetContent
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = label

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 1000.0


        }

    return cell
    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let sweet = sweets[indexPath.row]

    if let sweetContent = sweet["content"] as? String {

        let label = sweet["label"] as? String

        let dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormat.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
        let dateString = dateFormat.stringFromDate(sweet.creationDate!)

        var timeAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "\(dateString)") { (action: UITableViewRowAction, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

            let firstActivityItem = self.sweets[indexPath.row]

            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [firstActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

            self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
        timeAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

        return [timeAction]

    }

    return nil}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First have your `modificationDate` be marked as queryable.

#### `Date Modified` in the picture.

[image]

Then set a date restriction for `modificationDate` with `NSPredicate`

```
let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
let date = now.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-60*60*24*3)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "modificationDate > %@", date)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Sweet", predicate: predicate)
```

Comment: Where do I implement that code within my tableviewcontroller.swift file? @Allen

Comment: @BrandonPriest Implement the predicate for ``CKQuery``.